# Translate "The given data was invalid." in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, validation

how can I translate "The given data was invalid." to Laravel 5.6?
Thank you

Comment: How do you output the data? When validation fails it returns the error and you get `The given data was invalid`. What do you do with it?

Could you wrap it in a `trans()` function and get translation from files there?

Answer (score 16):

find and replace that message in `resources/lang/{lang_code}/validation`

```
   'exists'               => 'The selected :attribute is invalid.',
```

change here with your language instead of `:attribute`

**OR**

add below lines added into render() method of the file `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`

```
if ($exception instanceof ValidationException)
  return response()->json(['message' => 'Your error message here', 'errors' => $exception->validator->getMessageBag()], 422); //type your error code.
```

Happy coding~! :)

Comment: Thanks for $validator->getMessageBag()

Comment: I needed the full path of the class: `if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException)` - as noted by Luka Sh below

Answer (score 11):

"The given data was invalid." is hard coded

File: *src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.php*

```
    public function __construct($validator, $response = null, $errorBag = 'default')
    {
   -    parent::__construct('The given data was invalid.');
   +    parent::__construct(__('The given data was invalid.'));
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->errorBag = $errorBag;
```

From commit:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/22112/commits/b70372fd0031e5fabaee462c913b19b665becaf3

Answer (score 8):

As JsWizard already mentioned above you can handle that specific exception by adding following lines to `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`

Just to improve his answer, you need to include ValidationException

```
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException as ValidationException;
```

and then add following to the `render()` method:

```
if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {

    return response()->json(['message' => 'YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE HERE', 'errors' => $exception->validator->getMessageBag()], 422);

}
```

Comment: `ValidationException as ValidationException`? What's the point of `as ValidationException` since you don't change the name of it?

Answer (score 7):

in laravel 8 app/Exceptions/Handler.php just overwrite the method as following

```
/**
 * Convert a validation exception into a JSON response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
protected function invalidJson($request, ValidationException $exception)
{
    return response()->json([
        'message' => __('validation.headermsg'),
        'errors' => $exception->errors(),
    ], $exception->status);
}
```

thats it enjoy

Comment: And don't forget to add to the top use of \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException. Best regards

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for late reply, I found a method working in Laravel 5.8 and above.
I hope you  were still looking for an answer, here is mine.

As Official Docs from Laravel explains:

> *When using the `validate` method during an AJAX request, Laravel will not generate a redirect response. Instead, Laravel generates a JSON response containing all of the validation errors. This JSON response will be sent with a 422 HTTP status code.*

So, you cannot translate the response, because is part of the core of laravel and is hardcoded, and do the same in the response is not a solution.

So I recommend you to use the Request Validation method for your forms, and then extend the method called `failedValidation(Validator $validator)` which is part of FormRequest class.

You can create a new RequestValidation with the artisan console:
`php artisan make:request FooRequest`

When you had your `FooRequest.php` file, add the method **failedValidation** method with the suggested lines:

```php
/**
 * Handle a failed validation attempt.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator  $validator
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    /**
     * @var array $response Is our response data.
     */
    $response = [
        "success" => false, // Here I added a new field on JSON response.
        "message" => __("Los datos enviados no son válidos."), // Here I used a custom message.
        "errors" => $validator->errors(), // And do not forget to add the common errors.
    ];

    // Finally throw the HttpResponseException.
    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($response, 422));
}
```

And the result of our 422 responses is:

[I used Postman for the Request, check the response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbTML.png)

I hope it helps for future references.

Best Regards

Comment: Thank's for the tip. I had resolve one bug including Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException instead of Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException

Answer (score 2):

Sadly the Laravel team marked this as a non issue (they're pretty stubborn in this kind of things).

The cleanest way i found to circumnvent the issue is to add to `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` this code:

```
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ValidationException)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json([
                'message'=>__($e->getMessage()),
                'errors'=> $e->errors(),
            ],$e->status);
        }
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Then add the translation in `resources/lang/[language-code].json`; for example for italy create a file named `resources/lang/it.json` with this content:

```
{
    "The given data was invalid." : "I dati inseriti contengono errori."
}
```

The code will only replace the message string in JSON response (as needed).

Comment: I don't downvote because it works, but it is wrong. YOU SHOULD NEVER USE A VARIABLE INSIDE TRANSLATOR FUNCTIONS IN ANY PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE ANYWHERE EVER! Because static analysis tools later won't be able to extract right translations, so do yourself a favor and never use this!

Comment: A translation function as a function should be able to receive any value as an input, nothing wrong with that code wise.
I do understand the concept behind static analysis and problems due to that but forcing your way of programming is not an excuse, 
This is just a workaround due to the total lack of localization in some areas and my main goal was to make it as transparent as possible; static analysis should also be able to read the keys from the JSON file or you could use my example as an actual example and just write a static if-else.